# MVC Session Possibly Not Saving. Possibly Dump Contents To Page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm having an issue with my MVC site when I'm trying to do security, I'm getting a list of groups from AD, comparing them to a user and then attempting to create a custom security object which I then save to `Session`.

This `Session` is then meant to determine whether or not the user can view pages.  It works fine in my local development environment, but in my test system (separate box) it doesn't work and I get Access Denied (as expected if the user isn't a member of a specific group).

The code doesn't throw any errors but when I try and retrieve the session for my `SECURITY_ACCESS` object it doesn't seem to find anything.

Is it possible, for the purposes of checking whether the session is infact populated temporarily, that I can dump the entire contents of the session to a page?

In my `View` for the AccessDenied controller I've got the following, but whilst it says there is an object in the Session it doesn't actually output it.

```
@foreach (string item in Session.Keys)
{
<tr>
<td>
<strong>Session: </strong>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item))
</td>
</tr>
}
```

I am starting to pull my hair out with this problem as I just can't see why it is not working in Test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suggest that you do not put security components in session. I would also encourage you not to roll your own authorization system. Instead, use the security components built into MVC. An overview of the components is here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security. The built-in `AuthorizeAttribute` can be used with Windows Auth to specify AD groups which should have access to a page, as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322(v=vs.98).aspx.

In answer to your question:

The `HttpSessionState` is annoyingly difficult to work with; I wish it would just implement `IDictionary<string,object>`. Anyway, here's a somewhat verbose way to dump the session to the page.

```
@{
    var sessionItems = Session.Keys.OfType<string>().ToDictionary (k => k, k => session[k]);    
    var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sessionItems, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
}
<pre>
    @Html.Raw(json);
</pre>
```

Comment: The way the backend DB has been developed (out of my hands) I have to really create my own Security object. Plus I have a few different groups that will eventually be used granted full write, partial write, read-only to the application. Would using the likes of the Authorize attribute not make this difficult?  

For now I'm stuck with getting this initial security feature working, but I can refactor it to potentially use Authorize roles once I get this released to test.

Comment: I've just been reading through that stuff and I actually rather like it.  The only thing I have about it is I don't want a dialog to popup asking for login credentials, I would rather it redirected to an AccessDenied page.   Is this possible?

The link provided to MSDN also requires changing features in IIS which I will not have the ability to do.  Is this a restriction?  If so I will still have to go with my original method.

Comment: @MattR, with Windows Auth the popup credential challenge is a browser-dependent response to an NTLM negotiation; in my experience IE will just use the credentials you logged into Windows with, but other browsers will use the popup. You can derive a class from `AuthorizeAttribute` and force a redirect instead of a challenge, but that may prevent you from using Windows Auth at all.

Comment: @MattR, the `AuthorizeAttribute` can be applied to classes and to methods, so you can have different restrictions on your POST and GET methods. If that's getting too complicated you could take a look at FluentSecurity (http://www.fluentsecurity.net/getting-started), which gives you a single configuration point for authorization. If your `Security` object is simple enough, consider embedding it in the user's identity token rather than session, so it will be encrypted and will not be serialized to the session store. Even better would be to switch to claims-based auth...

Comment: unfortunately I can't use any 3rd party DLLs / APIs. I'm very much restricted to what I have "out of the box" in Visual Studio. Any tips or examples for using the `AuthorizeAttribute` like you've briefly described in your 2nd comment? I would definitely need to do a redirect as I can't restrict the browser used. This is for an internal app so the users will have multiple browsers and want to just log straight in / get kicked out. I don't think I will have time to try and implement the `Authorize` idea fully in this phase.